# How to filter views using Ajax

Tags: ajax, views

I have an array that I stock in the browser's storage. I retrieve it in Javascript.

I'd like to use those values to display a view. They IDs represent a nid.

I already created a view, took a wildguess and decided to use the contextual filters, allowing me to pass parameters in the URL.

But now, I'm stuck.

Any hints/tips ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Contextual filters in this case, cause they are sent in url - use exposed filter.

Exposed filter will create form, which you can fill in and submit by js-code. Turn on AJAX fro view and filters will also work via AJAX.